# What is wrong with my approach to this BPHO problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I am a tutor, and one of my students is practicing for the BPHO. One of the problems he wanted to go over is below.

[image: screenshot of the BPHO problem]

I decided to use the fact that

$$F_{net}=\frac{dp}{dt}=M\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{dM}{dt}v$$

for $M$ the total mass. From there, you can set up an ODE for $v$ and solve. However, in the official solutions for that problem, they instead set up their ODE as
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{F_{net}}{M}$$

These ODEs have different (though similar) solutions, but I can't think of why my approach would be considered incorrect.

EDIT: To be clear, my issue here is why taking $F_{net}=Ma$, as the examiners did, is considered to be correct, while $F_{net}=\frac{dp}{dt}$ is not. Am I missing or forgetting some reason the latter would just simplify to the former?

Comment: @WillO Yes, I am aware. Hence why I have a dM/dt term in that momentum derivative. Similarly, the official solution also has M as a function of time.

Comment: I misread what you were saying, so my comment is irrelevant.  I am deleting it, with apologies.

Comment: I have voted to reopen.  It seems to me there is an interesting conceptual question here.

Comment: I think your method is right, don't really see why there wouldn't be a $\dot m v$ term. I have heard from others that BPhO can sometimes be incorrect and this may be one of those problems (do take that with a grain of salt as I have never done any BPhO problem before).

Comment: Unless in the BPHO solution they didn't somehow put the $\dot{M}v$ term into their $F_{net}$ I would agree with you and Ashmit Dutta.